# linux kernel patch signed-off-by line

Tags: linux-kernel, patch

Basically, I'm stuck on task 4 of the Eudyptula challenge.

I ran the submission through checkpatch.pl. The only error I got was from a missing signed-off-by line.

I added the signed-off-by line, ran it through checkpatch.pl again, and it received no errors so I submitted the patch. I received a reply that says the scripts for this task can't handle patches.

I removed the diff lines so that only the code and the signed-off-by line were left, and the submission still didn't pass.

Has anybody else on here completed this task?

Comment: I have completed it. Though I don't have any complains about Signed-off-by line. I don't even have that line at all. I just attached my fixed files and sent it. You can ask Little about what's wrong, showing how you launch checkpatch.pl.

Comment: It's that I run it through checkpatch.pl and everything is fine. I only get 3 warnings. Everything else is perfect. How can I ask little what's wrong? Isn't little just a script? How would little know what to answer me?

Comment: You have to fix all warnings. And don't be afraid to ask Little - it's a script but there is human.

Comment: Oh okay. In the email it just says errors. The warnings all have to do with deprecated code and it says not to change any of the logic so I figured I should just ignore them. Thanks.

Comment: I too am stuck with this. I get warnings as --                **WARNING: Prefer [subsystem eg: netdev]_dbg([subsystem]dev, ... then dev_dbg(dev, ... then pr_debug(...  to printk(KERN_DEBUG ...
/home/venkatesh/Desktop/task-4/hello.c:12: WARNING: Prefer [subsystem eg: netdev]_dbg([subsystem]dev, ... then dev_dbg(dev, ... then pr_debug(...  to printk(KERN_DEBUG ...
total: 0 errors, 2 warnings, 13 lines checked**  Althought there are no errors with the code. The isse lies in this area of code -- line12  -- **printk(KERN_DEBUG "Hello World module unloaded successfully");**

Comment: Do not publicly discuss euduptyla-tasks! Rule no. 1.

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to navigate here in the dark but:

To signed-off correctly do:

```
git commit -s --amend
```

In case you created a new change and want to add (`-a`) all the changes:

```
git commit -s -a
```